# Seem unable to edit form field in AX 2012 - X++

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm working on AX 2012 in X++ and am trying to add functionality to the LogisticsPostalAddress form part. Part of the functionality needs to populate the form (before the changes are saved), but I don't seem to be able to populate the fields.

I have found reference to using the following code:

```
LogisticsPostalAddress_ZipCode.text("NewCode");
```

This doesn't seem to work. If I use:

```
LogisticsPostalAddress.ZipCode = "NewCode";
```

The form doesn't change, but if I save and reopen the form the data has been changed.

I need to populate the fields on the form so that the user can see the new values before closing the form. Any suggestions?

Kevin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
LogisticsPostalAddress.ZipCode = "NewCode";
LogisticsPostalAddress_ds.refresh();
```